# « Bon ben j'pense que j'vais retontir dans ma piscine moi » ?

Tags: sens, étymologie, québec, régionalismes

Bernard, Fernand et Georges discutent au jardin. Après un moment de silence, Fernand se lève en disant :

> — Bon ben j'pense que j'vais *retontir* [əʀ' tɔ ̃ ti:ʀ, avec l'[interversion](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4506)] dans ma piscine moi.

Ce verbe n'apparaît pas à première vue dans un [dictionnaire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/retontir) français. On l'a déjà entendu dans le contexte de l'[*arrivée inopinée*](http://www.wikebec.org/retontir/definition/).

---

1. De quel *sens* s'agit-il précisément (au propre/figuré; quelle acception selon contexte; pourquoi) ?
2. Quelle est l'*origine/l'étymologie* de ce verbe ?
3. Ce sens est-il propre au Québec ou l'entend-on ailleurs dans la francophonie ?

Comment: Belge de 36 ans, je n'avais jamais entendu ce verbe auparavant... et effectivement après une rapide recherche cela semble très québecois...

Comment: « ... j' ... j' ... ma ... moi. ». Je ne sais pas si ça retonte mais ça redonde...

Comment: Pour l'étymologie récente et *"québistissiste"* : http://oreilletendue.com/2013/12/06/tontir-une-deuxieme-fois/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Malheureusement, ce mot n'apparaît pas dans la BDLP, ni dans Usito. Ma réponse ne sera que partielle.

Le mot a un article dans *NTC's Dictionary of Canadian French* de Robinson et Smith ainsi que dans le *Dictionnaire des Canadianismes* de Dulong.

Dans le premier, les traductions proposées sont "to bounce; to turn up; to ring, echo". Les synonymes sont "rebondir; reparaître; retentir". (Mais le mot apparaît avec un astérisque, ce qui signifie qu'il s'agit d'un "colloquial word or expression for which an appropriate North American English equivalent could not be found".)

Le deuxième donne aussi les trois sens, mais les assortit d'exemples.

> **RETONTIR** v. intr.
>   1. Arriver à l'improviste. On ne serait pas surpris de le voir *retontir* au milieu de la nuit. Syn.: **ressoudre** (sens 2).
>   2. [#] Rebondir. Une balle de caoutchouc qui *retontit* bien. Syn.: **ressoudre** (sens 3).
>   3. Retentir, se répercuter. À l'époque de la chasse, les coups de fusil *retontissaient* jusqu'ici.

Il est difficile d'être certain, à partir de ces informations, quel serait le sens exact dans la phrase donnée, mais je pencherais pour le deuxième sens de Dulong, soit "rebondir".

Le dictionnaire de Dulong ayant eu (en 1989) un objectif partiellement prescriptif, il utilise le symbole # qui veut dire "à déconseiller" concernant le deuxième sens. Contrairement au *NTC*, Dulong ne qualifie pas le mot de familier.

La prononciation *ertontir* provient, premièrement, de la chute du schwa entre le *r* et le *t*, et deuxièmement de l'ajout d'une voyelle épenthétique, comme dans *arien*.

Le Wiktionnaire ne donne aucune source pour dire que le mot viendrait de *retentir*. C'est donc à prendre avec précaution. Il se pourrait bien que *retentir* et *retontir* soient apparentés, sans que l'un vienne de l'autre.

Les sources consultées ne donnent aucune information sur l'utilisation de ce terme dans le reste de la francophonie. Il faudrait en premier lieu consulter des ouvrages sur le français acadien et sur le français louisianais pour savoir. Visiblement, il n'est pas utilisé à Paris, mais on ne peut pas exclure qu'il existe ailleurs en Europe francophone sans consulter des ouvrages spécialisés dans le lexique suisse, belge, et régional français.

**Ajout**. À la demande de Divulgâchâmes, voici l'article pour *ressoudre* dans le Dulong

> **RESSOUDRE, RESSOURDRE** v. intr. défectif[#]
>   1. Sourdre, en parlant de l'eau, d'une source. L'eau *ressourd* à deux pas d'ici.
>   2. Fig. Arriver à l'improviste, en parlant d'une personne. Syn.: **retontir** (sens 1).
>   3. Rebondir. Lancer une balle sur le ciment pour la faire *ressourdre*. Syn.: **retontir** (sens 2).

Le participe passé *ressous* a son propre article. Se conjugue avec *avoir*.

Comment: Oui, des versions papier.

Comment: Excellent! Donc c'était [sourdre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sourdre), ce qui inclut _jaillir_; j'étais passé à côté de ça avec résoudre etc. C'est donc 1100 Roland, et c'est du côté acadien que ça s'est transporté. J'ai trouvé un exemple dans la litt. québécoise, [ici](http://www.persee.fr/web/revues/home/prescript/article/caief_0571-5865_1989_num_41_1_1705?_Prescripts_Search_tabs1=standard&) (p.84-85). Merci encore!

Comment: Une recherche sur Google montre que *ressourdre* et *ressoudre* apparaissent aussi dans les dictionnaires du français louisianais, dont celui de Valdman. Malheureusement, je n'ai pas accès à la page qui correspondrait à *retontir*. Le dictionnaire s'intitulant *Les Acadiens louisianais et leur parler* mentionne à la fois *ressoudre* et *retondir* - en accès partiel sur Google Books. *Ressoudre* figure dans la BDLP-Acadie en ligne.

Comment: @Divulgâchâmes Merci pour la récompense!

Comment: Avec plaisir! On aime bien les sources et l'effort! Et au final quand on regarde la question avec les 3 réponses, on en a pour son argent retontissant assurément! Salutations.

Answer (score 2):

Je n'ai jamais entendu ce mot en France. Le [Wiktionnaire indique](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/retontir) :

2. que le mot est une déformation du verbe *retentir* ;
3. trois définitions, toutes provenant du Québec.

Concernant la première question, j'imagine qu'une extension de la définition 2. (« Rebondir ») pourrait s'apparenter à « faire un plongeon ». Si je ne me trompe pas, un équivalent qui me semble de même niveau serait :

> Bon, j'crois que j'vais piquer une tête dans ma piscine, moi !

Ceci est à prendre avec prudence en attendant confirmation car il ne s'agit que de déductions.

Comment: @YohannV. Merci pour les corrections. Remarque mineure : déduction était au singulier volontairement. Je désignais le processus et non l'unique déduction de ma réponse. :)

Comment: Je n'ai pas fait grand-chose ! Excuse moi d'avoir changé ce que tu disais mais n'aurais-tu pas dû dire *"**d'une** déduction"* alors? (J'ai été désolé de voir que tu avais enlevé "*des pincettes*" )

Comment: @YohannV. Encore une fois, je parlais du processus de déduction, non du résultat. :) J'aurais effectivement pu dire « d'une déduction ».

Comment: Hum, je crois que j'ai compris ... désolé pour la lourdeur ! T_T

Comment: Merci! Généralement le sens convient, aller faire un petit saut dans...

Answer (score 2):

Le verbe **retentir** a des sens moins usités/sortis d'usage; par analogie,  *produire de l'effet*<sup>1</sup>
Le verbe *retondir* est une ancienne variante de *retentir*<sup>2</sup>
Le verbe *retentir* est formé avec le préfixe re- et l'ancien [*tentir*](http://atilf.atilf.fr/scripts/dmfX.exe?IDF=dmfXeXrmXtcdf;ISIS=isis_dmf2012.txt;MENU=menu_dmf;OUVRIR_MENU=2;s=s172c0d38;LANGUE=FR;FERMER;AFFICHAGE=2;MENU=menu_dmf;;XMODE=STELLa;FERMER;;); *tentir* du latin populaire *tinnitare*, le fréquentatif du classique [*tinnire*](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?q=tinnit). Il y a l'idée de l'espace (délimité) par le bruit.

---

Le verbe **rebondir** a des sens moins usités; tels *reprendre de la vigueur* après un obstacle, *faire jaillir*
Le verbe *rebondir* signifie à l'origine *retentir*<sup>3</sup>
Le verbe *rebondir* est formé avec le préfixe re- et [*bondir*](http://atilf.atilf.fr/scripts/dmfX.exe?IDF=dmfXgXrmXbgfa;ISIS=isis_dmf2012.txt;MENU=menu_dmf;OUVRIR_MENU=2;s=s172c0d38;LANGUE=FR;FERMER;AFFICHAGE=1;MENU=menu_dmf;;XMODE=STELLa;FERMER;;), du latin populaire *bombitire*<sup>4</sup>; bas latin *bombitare*, fréquentatif du classique [*bombire*](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?q=bombio) (bourdonner, les abeilles); beaucoup calqué sur le grec. L'idée de bond n'est pas présente au début, apparaît tardivement; c'est le son<sup>5</sup> qui tourne et sa cadence.

---

Le [*FEW*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz%C3%B6sisches_Etymologisches_W%C3%B6rterbuch) nous permet d'*explorer* les formes gallo-romanes par *etymon* directement, dont ceux dont on a traité, et en voici quelques éléments  :

> [*tǐnnīre*](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/lire/131/345) : à *retondir*, pour *retentir*, on trouve la forme
>   *èrtondi* ou *retonti*.<sup>6</sup> On découvre aussi des dérivés insoupçonnés aux suffixes altérés, comme *courir la prétantaine*, avec
>   une forme *courir l'pèrtontinne*, être toujours par voies et par
>   chemins; ou même culbuter, faire une chute.
>
> [*tǐnnǐtare*](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/lire/131/346) : on y trouve des dérivés dont le *retinton*,
>   généralement le *petit reliquat*, mais aussi *répétition*, *retour*,
>   *petit reste imprévu*. Comme on l'a vu dans le lien de le question, souvent la métathèse joue un rôle, d'où l'intérêt d'explorer les
>   anciennes formes voisines/régionales.
>
> [*bombitire*](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/lire/10/429) : *manière particulièrement retentissante de sonner
>   les instruments de musique militaire pour animer les guerriers*.
>   Bearn. *arreboundi*, répercuté. *Rebond*, renouvellement d'une fête.
>   *Tout d'ébondie*, d'un vif élan; *abondir*, accourir; *fourbondir*, sauter dessus. *Bondi*, bord d'une robe.
>
> [*tǔnt-*](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/218799) : *Tounterie*, niaiserie. *Retontir*, rebondir; cogl.
>   *ərtõdi* retentir; faire écho.
>
> [ courts extraits adaptés du *Französisches Etymologisches Wörterbuch. Eine darstellung des
>   galloromanischen sprachschatzes*, Walther von Wartburg, 1922/2002 ]

---

Au Québec, dans un [ouvrage](https://books.google.fr/books?id=pivEs6urQZ4C&vq=retontir&hl=fr&source=gbs_navlinks_s) basé sur le lexique du manuscrit du [maire Viger](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Viger)<sup>7</sup> du début du 19<sup>e</sup>, on recense (pp. 221-222) deux sens majeurs à *retontir* avec références aux origines: 1. *Rebondir*, Touraine, parlers poitevins *retontiner*, encore courant au Québec. 2. *Retentir* 14<sup>e</sup> wallon *retondir*; les deux formes *retondir*, *retontir*, Bretagne romane, Normandie, Saintonge, Poitou, Champagne, langue d'oc; encore courant au Québec. On s'appuie sur le FEW.

---

Quant à une réponse, bien je trouve aussi le *bond* séduisant, peut-être davantage le changement de trajectoire et l’amerrissage ici; mais peut-être aussi l'idée de désinvolture, d'occuper l'espace avec son tintamarre pourrait-on dire. C'est que les formes et le sens se sont croisés dès le départ, et le *retontir* semble un amalgame de retentir et rebondir qui s'adapte à toutes les situations ou presque au Québec. On a sans doute déjà entendu dans la francophonie, il y a longtemps, à tout le moins *retondir*...<sup>8</sup>

---

<sub>**1.** « *Comme je le sans retantir ! Dieu, quel fort vin ! comme il point ! Je suis yvre, or est a point, Vin est trop perilleux bruvaige, Quil peu en bura sera saige.* » (Pass. Semur D.M., c.1420 [1488], 31)., au [*Dictionnaire du moyen français*](http://atilf.atilf.fr/scripts/dmfX.exe?IDF=dmfXgXrmXrhgb;ISIS=isis_dmf2012.txt;MENU=menu_dmf;OUVRIR_MENU=2;s=s170c0e38;LANGUE=FR;FERMER;AFFICHAGE=2;MENU=menu_dmf;;XMODE=STELLa;FERMER;;). Au [Godefroy D.](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/retentir), faire contraste : « que celle blancheur [de la chair] retentist par sa beaulté a l'encontre de ses vestements qui estoient d'un vermeil [...] » (Perceforest, 1528) au GDD (voir usuellement [*GDC*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/complement-godefroy/retentir)). **2.** La [remarque au *DmF*](http://atilf.atilf.fr/scripts/dmfX.exe?IDF=dmfXfXrmXrYdbbb;ISIS=isis_dmf2012.txt;MENU=menu_dmf;OUVRIR_MENU=2;s=s172c0d38;LANGUE=FR;FERMER;AFFICHAGE=2;MENU=menu_dmf;;XMODE=STELLa;FERMER;;) se demande si c'est l'influence de *ton* sur *retentir*, et on note des variantes, dont *retendir*. Le *GDD* note directement à *retondir* « Canada, *retontir*. ». Donc on disait au Canada *retontir* pour dire *retondir* qui veut dire *retentir* dans ce contexte. **3.** Jusqu'au 16e (*DHLF*/Rey). Au GDC, [*rebondir*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/rebondir) : « *Li poples Deu duna un merveillus cri, que tute la terre rebondi.* » (*Rois*, ds. de Lincy). **4.** On dit que le prototype *tinitire* sert *peut-être* de modèle à cette graphie. **5.** On remarque par exemple une curiosité comme *bondir l'eau*, c'est-à-dire *faire retentir un instrument* donnant le signal de se laver des mains avant un repas. (au *DmF*, *bondir*). **6.** On parle aussi du f*ressoundi/ressounti*, très proche de *résonner*. Certaines sources assimilent un troisième sens distinct à *retontir* (au Québec), soit le synonyme de *ressoudre*, mais on n'en étaye pas l'étymologie. On a un verbe [*ressouder*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ressouder) qui veut dire réunir par la suture, mais qui peut être utilisé au figuré; autrement ce serait [*résoudre*](http://atilf.atilf.fr/scripts/dmfX.exe?IDF=dmfXgXrmXrgih;ISIS=isis_dmf2012.txt;MENU=menu_dmf;OUVRIR_MENU=2;s=s04232c38;LANGUE=FR;FERMER;AFFICHAGE=2;MENU=menu_dmf;;XMODE=STELLa;FERMER;;) (empl. pron. trouver son *aboutissement*, se décider à) ?? Mon expérience est que je n'ai *jamais* entendu *il va bien finir par ressoudre/résoudre* pour dire de quelqu'un qu'il va arriver/se pointer, mais historiquement des sources au Canada l'ont ainsi [documenté](https://archive.org/stream/leparlerpopulair00dionuoft#page/570/mode/2up)([2](https://archive.org/stream/dictionnairedebo00blanuoft#page/242/mode/2up)), lui donnant même aussi le sens de *rebondir* pour la balle. **7.** *Néologie canadienne, ou, Dictionnaire des mots créés en Canada & maintenant en vogue, des mots dont la prononciation & orthographe françoises, quoique employés dans une acception semblable ou contraire, et des mots étrangers qui se sont glissés dans notre langue*, Jacques Viger, Suzelle Blais, Presses de l'Université d'Ottawa, 1998. **8.** Pour le *retontir* qui m'a inspiré la question, voir [Les Voisins](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Voisins_%28film,_1987%29) (1980) de C. Meunier/L. Saïa, @13:21; impayable.</sub>