# « Manger une volée de bois vert » : des coups qui se perdent en volée lyrique ?

Tags: sens, usage, expressions-idiomatiques, registre, sport

L'expression [*prendre sa volée*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/vol%C3%A9e/82447/locution?q=prendre%20une%20vol%C3%A9e#184538), de registre littéraire, signifie *s'envoler ; quitter son foyer ; s'émanciper* (Larousse). C'est non sans rappeler la métaphore littéraire *donner la [volée](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vol%C3%A9e) à qqn/qqc*. pour « accorder pleine liberté à une personne, donner libre cours à une chose » (TLFi)...

---

D'autre part, pour le type *volée de coups* (1650), on a la *volée de bois vert* (1784), surtout au [figuré](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/vol%C3%A9e/82447/locution?q=vol%C3%A9e%20de%20bois%20vert#184540) (les *critiques acerbes*, 1860) ; on pouvait aussi la *donner* dans le sens de [*battre, maltraiter*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bois/1) quelqu'un, et d'ailleurs on nous dit que l'emploi de la *volée de bois vert* est disparu au propre (DHLF/Rey). C'est avec une certaine déception qu'on comprend cependant que la *volée de coups* pour la *série de coups/les coups nombreux* est basée sur l'idée du *mouvement vif*, devenant de manière absolue des « coups assénés à la suite », et non sur l'envolée (du coup) qui serait l'apanage des emplois plus [littéraires](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/vol%C3%A9e/82447), semble-t-il. Au Canada, et assurément au Québec, on connaît bien l'emploi de *[manger](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/manger) des coups, une [dégelée](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/d%C3%A9gel%C3%A9e/22815?q=d%C3%A9gel%C3%A9e#22699) (!), une [raclée](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/racl%C3%A9e/65940?q=racl%C3%A9e#65193), la volée* dans le sens d'*être battu* nous dit-on (TLFi). Par ailleurs, on a le [*soufflet*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/soufflet), la *baffe*, la *gifle*, la *claque*, de registres variés mais limités au visage surtout. Puis on a des spécialisations comme la [*bastonnade*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bastonnade), soit la volée de *coups de bâtons*. Au Québec on a déjà entendu (se faire) *passer au [batte](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/batte/1)*, se rappelant au passage qu'au baseball on n'a pas qu'une simple branche, pour se faire tabasser au propre comme au figuré (voir [discussion](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/un-coup-de-semonce.php) sur l'inadéquation avec le *coup de semonce* au cours duquel on ne passe pas nécessairement un mauvais quart d'heure).

Mais finalement il ne semble que dans aucun cas ce ne soit en effet l'équivalent de ce qui *revole* ou qui *fait revoler* ; ce verbe s'emploie différemment au Québec de l'emploi comme avec le rossignol déconfit de l'[*Harmonie des sphères*](https://books.google.com/books?redir_esc=y&id=96McAQAAIAAJ&dq=L%27Harmonie%20des%20sph%C3%A8res&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=rossignol) qui vola de nouveau, et l'on entend plutôt « rebondir » et « jaillir en s'éparpillant, en se dispersant » (DHLF/Rey, notant avec justesse qu'on prononce *[ar](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/14273)voler*), autorisant à tout le moins l'idée d'ascension sinon d'envol pur et simple... Autrement dit une volée au propre peut faire revoler mais pas nécessairement, puisqu'un seul impact pourrait entraîner l'envol du destinataire, et qu'on ne dirait d'un seul coup qu'il constituât une volée (?).

---

- Qu'est-ce que le *bois vert* ; dans un exemple au TLFi on disait que
  c'était destiné à un *maroufle* (*Fracasse*) et dans un [autre](https://books.google.com/books?redir_esc=y&id=PNkxAAAAMAAJ&dq=ludovic%20hal%C3%A9vy%20%22vol%C3%A9e%20de%20bois%20vert%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22bois%20vert%22)
  on ne sait pas trop ; et incidemment en quoi ça diffère du bâton
  (ultimement de *baseball*) en ce qui a trait à l'emploi ou au public
  cible, justement ; de quelle propriété du bois s'agit-il, est-il
  d'une espèce particulière ou d'une couleur verte, s'agit-il d'une
  propriété qu'il partage avec le *fouet*, est-ce une gradation de
  l'intensité du châtiment selon le matériau ou simplement la modernité
  ou l'archaïsme des références qui font la nuance ?
- Quand quelqu'un est [amoché](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/amoch%C3%A9) lors d'une bagarre et qu'on
  l'aperçoit par la suite, quelle locution composée d'un pronom (tu,
  il/elle), d'un verbe (prendre, recevoir, flanquer, manger, ou en
  emploi pronominal...) et d'un nom précédé d'un article/déterminant
  (la volée etc.), peut-être suivi de son complément, emploie-t-on le
  plus spontanément/usuellement pour décrire son état/ce que l'on pense
  qui s'est passé ?
- À la boxe ou en combat libre quand l'athlète reçoit un coup de poing particulier, comme l'*uppercut* (ou le [*shoryuken*](http://streetfighter.wikia.com/wiki/Shoryuken)), il y a une réaction de
  son corps dans l'espace (et sans doute un [son](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/12706)) : quel verbe ou locution emploierait-on pour
  décrire de manière usuelle l'aspect aérien du coup, de ce qui arrive
  à celui qui le reçoit, ou le phénomène dans son ensemble, et qui se
  rapprocherait le plus du sens de l'envol (*il/elle revole*, au Qc.) ?

Comment: Why is that downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Le bois vert, c'est le bois fraîchement coupé, encore « vivant » et chargé en sève. Ses caractéristiques mécaniques, sa grande souplesse et sa densité plus élevée aggravent les effets des coups comparé à du bois sec, plus léger et cassant.
2. « Tu t'es pris une raclée ». Dans le sud de la France au moins, on pourra aussi entendre « Il s'est mangé une raclée/une rouste ».
3. L'uppercut l'a envoyé au tapis.

Comment: Un Français m'a introduit au verbe _morfler_: «Il a morflé». C'est commun aussi? Mais peut-être le fait qu'il est (semble au moins) intransitif le disqualifie-t-il?

Comment: @Feelew Oui, « morfler » est courant mais intransitif.

Answer (score 0):

En effet, il n'y aucun lien direct (autre que chacun étant dérivé de *voler*) entre la *volée* (de coup, de tirs ou de bois vert), et le verbe *revoler* au sens "être projeté".

Par ailleurs, puisque tu emploies *manger* dans le titre de ta question, je présume que tu a rencontré l'expression dans un contexte Québécois. Un Québécois, au point 2 de jlliagre, dirait plutôt qu'il a *mangé* une raclée (ou plus génériquement, qu'il *en a mangé toute une*).

Comment: « Mangé » existe aussi à Marseille, mais sous la forme pronominale.